# Redirect output of javascript function to variable

Tags: javascript, variables, redirect, return

Is it possible in Javascript to redirect output intended for the web page to a variable instead?

I am calling a function hosted on another server which writes HTML data to my web page. But I want to keep that data in a variable instead of having it displayed directly.

Comment: do you mind adding some relevant code?

Comment: It's possible depending on details, of which you've provided too little to comment much.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DocumentFragment` and `appendChild()` the HTML to that. You can then append it later on whenever you need it.

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(htmldata);
//...
//later:
document.getElementById("mydiv").append(frag);
```

Is this the kind of thing you are looking for...?